# JSON request with JQuery/Ajax with Spring

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I'm very new to JSON/Spring MVC and am trying to get a simple example of an AJAX call to a Spring MVC controller - but I keep returning an error of 400 - Bad Request.

After scouring the Internet, I've found that this is usually caused by not setting the appropriate content type - but [I believe] I have done that.

Here is my AJAX call:

```
    //validate the object
    var urlString = "/ajax/add/";

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: urlString,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", 
        data: {value1: 'apples', value2 : 'oranges'},
        success: function(result){
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("error:" + textStatus + " exception:" + errorThrown);
        }

    }) ;
```

And my controller:

```
@Controller
itpublic class AddController {

private static Logger m_log = null;

@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/add")
public String handle(@RequestBody String json){

    DummyClass dummyRequest;
    try {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        dummyRequest = mapper.readValue(json, DummyClass.class);
        m_log.info("Value1: " + dummyRequest.getValue1());
        m_log.info("Value2: " + dummyRequest.getValue2());
    }  catch (Exception e) {

    }
    finally{


    }
    return "called";
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

*edit*

Here is my context that I use to configure Spring:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.do" />

<!--<mvc:annotation-driven/> -->

<bean class="com.project.do.interceptors.handler.mapping.HandlerInterceptorAnnotationAwareHandlerMapping "/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean class="com.project.do.viewresolver.ProjectViewResolver" >
    <property name="tilesResolver" ref="tilesResolver" />
    <property name="jspResolver" ref="jspResolver" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesResolver" class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>

<bean id="jspResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="3" />
</bean>

<bean id ="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml" />
    <property name="preparerFactoryClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringBeanPreparerFactory"/>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/javascript/**" location="/javascript/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/styles/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/help/**" location="/help/" />

<!-- <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome"/> -->
```

I should note that I have a working Controller with Ajax in the package com.project.do.working, but the nonworking Controller with Ajax and JSON is in the same package com.project.do.not.working

Comment: How are you configuring Spring? Could you edit the question and add your configuration details (probably an XML file unless you are using the newer @Configuration style).

Comment: I attached the context used to configure Spring.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you try replacing your RequestBody with @RequestParam String value1, ..(at)RequestParam String value2? and you do want to have method = RequestMethod.POST inside your ReequestMapping (as mentioned by raddykrish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your request mapping is not having the RequestMethod as POST. I guess by default it taking it a get request but your AJAX is a POST request. Try changing as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handle(@RequestBody String json){
}
```

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer, as it did appear to be required.  I actually had this coded originally, but started stripping out segments when things were not working.  The bulk of the problem appeared to be purely environmental in nature - something no one could have helped me out with.

Comment: @kjl, I'm facing a similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075101/400-bad-request-on-spring-jquery-ajax-post), can you please tell me what the real issue was ? It might help me

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee/add.htm")
public class EmployeeController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Employee add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {


    }
}
```