# Array of Objects comes like String to Spring controller from Ajax

Tags: java, arrays, spring

I pass array of items from JS to spring controller. I have this model in JS:

```
function Row() {
            this.id = 0;
            this.rulingValue = '';
            this.rulingType = '';
            this.dateStart = '';
            this.dateEnd = '';
        }
```

I have array of Rows - `var jsonData = [];`

Then I fill this array. And set to

```
var oMyForm = new FormData();
oMyForm.append("items", jsonData);
```

In Spring controller I expect this array like `List<Item>`

```
@Data
public class Item {
    private String id;
    private String rulingValue;
    private String rulingType;
    private String dateStart;
    private String dateEnd;
}

@RequestParam("items") List<Item> items
```

But my items parameter arrive as String. How can I get this array like `List<Item>`?

Comment: Use `@RequestBody`. `@RequestParam` for query strings.

Answer (score 0):

**Springs preferred way to send JSON to a Controller is as body payload rather than as form parameter.** To do so, you just have to do three things:

1. Make sure you have a JSON library in the classpath, e.g. fasterxml.jackson.
2. Ensure your JSON payload is sent via POST request with HTTP Content-Type "application/json"
3. Annotate the receiving parameter in your Controller handler method with @RequestBody, e.g.

   getItems(@RequestBody List items)

A complete example can be found here: http://www.beabetterdeveloper.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody.html

If you stay with sending your data as form parameter, you will have to write a custom property editor along the lines indicated here: [JSON parameter in spring MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577782/json-parameter-in-spring-mvc-controller). It is much harder and requires extra code.