# Multiple Multivalued attribute with @RequestParam as a Map

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
http://localhost:5000/product?cust_id=1&multi_attribute={"size":["xl","small"],"color":["red","green"]}
```

It is using multiple `multi_attributes`. I know how to do it in this way:

```
size= value1, value2
```

Also got to know that we can bind the object directly without `@RequestParam`.
But what I have to implement is in the above given format and not getting anything to implement this in search.

Anybody has any idea to implement the last parameter `multi_attribute`?

Comment: It seems that what you got there is not a "multiattribute", is JSON. Take a look a this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577782/json-parameter-in-spring-mvc-controller Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Yes. That is correct RubioRic. If I use UriComponentsBuilder for building the URI , it is giving me the uri as http://localhost:5000/product?cust_id=1&multi_attribute=com.model.MultiAttribute@4f4c88f9. This is how I have set UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(recomm_post_url)
    .queryParam("cust_id", context.get("cust_id"))
    .queryParam("multi_attribute", multiAttribute);