# Cannot use Map as a JSON @RequestParam in Spring REST controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, http-request-parameters

This controller

```
@GetMapping("temp")
public String temp(@RequestParam(value = "foo") int foo,
                   @RequestParam(value = "bar") Map<String, String> bar) {
    return "Hello";
}
```

Produces the following error:

```
{
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"
}
```

What I want is to pass some JSON with `bar` parameter:
http://localhost:8089/temp?foo=7&bar=%7B%22a%22%3A%22b%22%7D, where `foo` is `7` and `bar` is `{"a":"b"}`
Why is Spring not able to do this simple conversion? Note that it works if the map is used as a `@RequestBody` of a `POST` request.

Comment: And what is the input? My bet is that your query is not valid json.

Comment: http://localhost:8089/temp?blah=%7B%22a%22%20%3A%20%22b%22%7D
I want to pass
{"a" : "b"}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57748102/10976088

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked:
Just define a custom converter from `String` to `Map` as a `@Component`. Then it will be registered automatically:

```
@Component
public class StringToMapConverter implements Converter<String, Map<String, String>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convert(String source) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(source, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `Map<String, String>` you have to do the following:

```
@GetMapping("temp")
public String temp(@RequestParam Map<String, String> blah) {
    System.out.println(blah.get("a"));
    return "Hello";
}
```

And the URL for this is: `http://localhost:8080/temp?a=b`

With `Map<String, String>`you will have access to all your URL provided Request Params, so you can add `?c=d` and access the value in your controller with `blah.get("c");`

For more information have a look at: http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-mvc-request-param/ at section **Using Map with @RequestParam for multiple params**

**Update 1: If you want to pass a JSON as String you can try the following:**

If you want to map the JSON you need to define a corresponding Java Object, so for your example try it with the entity:

```
public class YourObject {

   private String a;

   // getter, setter and NoArgsConstructor

}
```

Then make use of Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to map the JSON string to a Java entity:

```
@GetMapping("temp")
public String temp(@RequestParam Map<String, String> blah) {
     YourObject yourObject = 
          new ObjectMapper().readValue(blah.get("bar"), 
              YourObject.class);
     return "Hello";
}
```

For further information/different approaches have a look at:   [JSON parameter in spring MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577782/json-parameter-in-spring-mvc-controller)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I actually want is to pass JSON as a parameter. See my updated question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I just hoped there was a cleaner solution than to use ObjectMapper explicitly.

Comment: could you map the JSON successfully?