# How to get variable HTML form values (POST) in Spring backend

Tags: java, spring, forms, rest, post

i'm fairly new to Java and the Spring Framework and this might be easy to solve but I cant find any solutions to this problem and other solutions don't fit my problem.

I want to implement a dynamic form, where the user inserts multiple Email addresses to send invitations. This form can dynamically be extended by JS. Every click adds another input field to my form. So now I have a variable amount of values I want to send to my Spring Backend. I was thinking that I have to use @ResponseBody and a Map to store the POST values in it and then iterate over it and (for example) copy them into an ArrayList or directly use my EmailService to send out an Email.

The problem is, Spring gives me an error:

> Resolved exception caused by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
>   type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

This is my HTML

```
<form method="post" id="send-invite-mail" th:action="@{/sendmail/sendInvitations}">
  <div id="formfields">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="Enter Email-Address ..."/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more form-groups are added here by JS -->
  <button type="submit" id="submitInvitation" class="btn btn-primary">Invite</button>
</form>
```

And this is what I use in the backend to get my values

```
@PostMapping("/sendmail/sendInvitations")
public void getInvitationList (@RequestBody Map<String, String> formData){
   List<String> adressList = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : formData.entrySet()) {
      adressList.add(entry.getValue());
   }
}
```

Right now I have no idea if I'm doing this correct or not. Appreciate any help.

Comment: please try to use the link , it will help to you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948178/cannot-use-map-as-a-json-requestparam-in-spring-rest-controller

Comment: The link you gave me is not for POST values, afaik.

Comment: @Quoteniraner see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML forms with `method='post'` send data as **form-url-encoded**.
So, In this case, Spring can not understand it as a RequestBody. 
Because, POST data with `@RequestBody` expects an content type as `application/json`. So, if you want to really send data as json, you have to remove the @RequestBody annotation.

Finally, you can specify content-type with `consumes` and use 
one of the following ways:

**1.** `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestBody`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendmail/sendInvitations",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody returnType methodName(@RequestParam Map<String, String> name) {
    ...
}
```

**2.** Remove `@RequestBody` and use your POJO class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendmail/sendInvitations",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody returnType methodName(YourPOJO pojo) {
    ...
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: actually he  is trying to ask  Map as a JSON in Spring REST controller ,I have already attach link above , but your answer is not matching  with the Question

Comment: Merci Ghasem, this (1.) worked perfectly fine! I always used RequestParam for known keys and thought that RequestBody would solve the issue since its used for models with multiple key/values or attributes. Thank you very much!