# 400 Bad request on Spring Jquery Ajax Post

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, http-post

I'm getting a 400 bad request on this POST request. Any idea what the issue is here ? Logs are [here](http://db.tt/0Dtl7PWu).

Controller

```
@Controller
public class AjaxController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/addKeys", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addKeys(@RequestParam(value="keys") ArrayList<Keys> keys){
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+keys);
    }
}
```

context-Servlet.xml

```
<beans>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.canon.fw.controller" />
    <bean id="defaultViews" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
</beans>
```

Ajax

```
tmpList = '[{"key":"camera","label":"Camera"},{"key":"mobile","label":"Mobile"}]';
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: ctx+'/ajx/addKeys',
  data: JSON.stringify({"keys": tmpList }),
  success: function(r){
      if(r.model.status=='success'){
          debugger;
          //glist.push(elem.key);
          //addToList(elem.key, elem.label);
          highlightInfoDisc();
      }
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

FireBug - URL

```
http://localhost:8080/Di/ajx/addKeys
```

Firebug - Response Headers

```
Cache-Control   must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length  1384
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Server  Jetty(6.1.26)
```

Firebug - Request Headers

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  74
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  JSESSIONID=7mymobst47ig1s7uqy2z1fvx4
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/Di/tiles/entNews.htm
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Firebug - Source

```
{"keys":[{"key":"canon","label":"Canon"},{"key":"ricoh","label":"Ricoh"}]}
```

Firebug - Response

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8080/Di/ajx/addKeys"
```

Comment: **General note:** To easily figure out the underlying issue: Start by adding a break-point in `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException.HttpMessageNotReadableException()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are posting JSON, not form data, but you are trying to read the `ArrayList<Keys>` as a form parameter.

Try changing your method signature from:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> addKeys(@RequestParam(value="keys") ArrayList<Keys> keys){
```

to

```
public ResponseEntity<String> addKeys(@RequestBody Keys[] keys){
```

That may not work since your JSON has an object that has a `keys` property that is the list of keys.  So you could try to change your ajax post data to something like

```
data: JSON.stringify(tmpList)
```

so that you are just posting the list instead of wrapping it in another object that has the keys element.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working.  I gave two options here, it would be helpful to future visitors if you specify which one fixed your problem.

Comment: I had to do both. But once I did that, I'm not getting an @RequestBody ArrayList<Keys> keys inside the method addKeys. I'm getting this ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> keys !! and I was getting a classcaseException !! Weird though !! Any Ideas how to make it automatically convert it to a List of Keys class ?

Comment: Instead of @ RequestBody ArrayList<Keys> keys as a parameter, changed it to @RequestBody Keys[] keys. Works fine now !

Comment: @digitaljoel that solved my problem 400 bad request...now my controller recives the request(200 ok)...koodos for the answer...

Comment: Thanks both of you guys for the answers and updates. It was the first time I realized the difference between "@RequestParam" and "@RequestBody"

Comment: For some reason, I am not able to convert it into a bean. So I had to use `Object` and its working fine!! It came as `LinkedHashMap`.