# Bad Request while passing JSON data to Spring Controller

Tags: json, spring, request

I refered to the post @ [400 Bad request on Spring Jquery Ajax Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075101/400-bad-request-on-spring-jquery-ajax-post)

But I'm still getting a 400 bad request even when I follow the suggestion provided in the earlier post. Can anyone please let me know where am I going wrong.

Controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "validateLine.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JSONResponse checkForExceptions(HttpSession session,@RequestBody  OrderLine[] lineData) { 

    // do something
}
```

And AJAX Call

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/order/validateLine.htm",
    data : aData,
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response){  
            // do Something
            }
    });
```

Data sent to server from FireBug

```
[{"lineId":"2","itemDesctiption":"Item Desc 2","bundleDescription":"Bundle Desc 2"},{"lineId":"2","itemDesctiption":"Item Desc 2","bundleDescription":"Bundle Desc 2"}]
```

And if I say @RequestBody ArrayList <OrderLine> lineData I get the data as LinkedHashMap and throws an Exception.

Comment: depending on how your object mapper is setup (i.e. failing on unknown properties) could it be the typo in itemDescription?  You have itemDesctiption (notice the 't' instead of 'r') and the mapper may not know how to handle that field unless you also have the same type in your OrderLine class.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That doesn't seem to be issue coz its missplet in the Object Class as well.

Comment: Thank you digitaljoel... it was indeed a typo but it was at lineId.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure it is returning the right content type:

```
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Also, while there, should only accept the right content type:

```
@RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/json")
```

Comment: I added the header I am still getting 400 Bad Request "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications." Has it something to do with the Spring version I am using. I am using 3.1.1

Comment: @Solubris Is there any way to catch this 400 Bad Request and handle as if it's an exception?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to figure out the issue after spending one day. Its a typo :( I was sending lineId from javascript but it my Object class it was lineID (uppercase D).

Thank you all for your time.Appreciate it.