# 400 Bad Request while posting Json Object

Tags: json, jsp, spring-mvc, http-status-code-400

i am trying to post jsonObject from jsp to controller and i am getting 400 Bad Request Error.

My jsp code

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'save.web',
   type: "post", 
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType:'application/json',
   data: "data="+JSON.stringify(jsonArray),
   success:function(data){

   }
   }); 

   });

  My json Object
var jsonArray="{"+'"'+"cds"+'"'+":"+"["; 
for(i=0;i<newRow.length;i++)
{
 jsonArray=jsonArray+"{"+'"'+"dno"  +'":'+newRow[0]+","+'"'+"CampaignCode"  
 +'":'+newRow[1]+","  +'"'+"CampaignName"+'":'+newRow[2]+","  
 +'"'+"ServiceNo"  +'":'+newRow[3]+"}";
}
jsonArray=jsonArray+"]}";
```

My controller Code

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/save.web", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public String save(WebRequest webRequest,Model model,HttpServletRequest    
 request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam CampaignDisplay[] cds)        
{

    for(CampaignDisplay inputs : cds){
        System.out.println(inputs.getId());
        }
    return "menu";

}
```

input Json Object which i am passing is
      {"cds":[{"dno":8,"CampaignCode":d,"CampaignName":e,"ServiceNo":f},
      {"dno":7,"CampaignCode":a,"CampaignName":b,"ServiceNo":c}]}

I dont know why ia m getting 400 erro? i ahve set the headers also

Answer (score 0):

seems the controller is not able to understand the request. The reason is "You are posting JSON, not form data, but you are trying to read  as a form parameter".
change your method to

```
**public String save(WebRequest webRequest,Model model,HttpServletRequest    
 request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestBody Map<String, Object> inputParameter)        
{**
```

Check this link for your reference **[400 Bad request on Spring Jquery Ajax Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075101/400-bad-request-on-spring-jquery-ajax-post)**